# Python - how can i send message every x seconds to websocket server?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a very simple websocket app that receives live data from a websocket connection.

The problem that i'm having is that i have to send a message to the server every 5 seconds to not get disconnected. Is there any way to do this in a non blocking way?

Here is what i tried, the problem with this is that the whole thread gets blocked by the `send_ping` function:

```
import websocket
import _thread
import time
import rel

def send_ping(ws):
    ws.send("ping")
    time.sleep(5)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")
    test_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_ping, args=(ws,))
    test_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD",
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close)

    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=5)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection, 5 second reconnect delay if connection closed unexpectedly
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
    rel.dispatch()
```

**Note**: unfortunately using `ws.run_forever(ping_payload="ping", ping_timeout=5)` is not a solution because this library uses an opcode that the server doesn't recognize and [there is no way to change the opcode](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/882) without changing the source code of the library as far as i know

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a function for sending message and then call you function in a while loop then wait for 5 second to try again. for example:

```
import time
def send_message(message):
    your code here...
```

The while loop could be like this.

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
while True:
    send_message("my message")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) package and async function. There you can use [asyncio.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping) method which doesn't block thread.